# Is there a way to trigger a Drools rule based on its own metadata?

Tags: drools

I am trying to create a Drools 7.45.0 rule like so (pseudocode):

```
when
   <Have fact x>
   <Time since this rule was last fired is greater than y seconds>
then
   //Do something
```

I understand there are Rule objects that I can get metadata from, but if I don't add any metadata manually, there's nothing to retrieve. The `@timestamp` tag only seems to be applicable to events, not rules. Does Drools have a way to do this? If not, would there be a viable workaround?

Comment: Have you looked at the [temporal operators](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#cep-temporal-operators_decision-engine)?

Comment: Yes, but those seem to only act on events/facts, not on the rules themselves. Unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: Rules are conditions and consequences. The temporal operators can be used to measure time since the condition was last met and behave accordingly. It's functionally the same thing, and it's better to get out of the habit of thinking of rules as objects.